# How to find where the records exists in the array or not using c#

Tags: linq, lambda

I am having an array of elements and records. I want to display all the records that only contains records in the array.

For eg:

array contains: `[1,2,3]`
records contains: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

I want to display only `1,2,3` records. How to compare this in c#

Sorry for my english.

Comment: What do you mean 'not using C#'? You want to see the code in a different language?

Comment: he forgot to put comma after not in question :)

Comment: @Zia yah i forgot that

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using linq for query:

```
int[] array = new[] { 1,2,3 };
var record1 = new[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
var record2 = new[] { 4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
var records = new[] { record1, record2 };

// this will return record if at least one record in array is matched
var result1 = from r in records where array.Any(a => r.Contains(a)) select r;

// this will return record only if all items in array are matched
var result2 = from r in records where array.All(a => r.Contains(a)) select r;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 string[] a={"1","2","3"};
    string[] b={"1","2","3","4","1","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
    List<string> x=new List<string>();
    foreach (string s in a)
    {
        if (b.Contains(s))
        {
            //if you only wants to display
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            // if you want it to store , add it to a list
            if(!x.Contains(s))
            x.Add(s);
        }
    }
```